# How can I use bamboolib in Databricks?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, exploratory-data-analysis

I would like to automatically do Exploratory Data Analysis using Azure Databricks, and I have seen the potential it has as shown for example in this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-easy-way-to-do-data-exploration-22b4b8e1dc20

But when following the same steps in Databricks the extension is not enabled. I have tested something like this:

```
import bamboolib as bam
import pandas as pd
```

Also testing adding the following lines to enable the extension:

```
bam.enable()

# Jupyter Notebook extensions
!python -m bamboolib install_nbextensions
```

I have also read that bamboolib is "joining forces" with Databricks but still don't find if it is not yet available or any documentation regarding this integrations.

I would really appreciate if anyone knows how to use bamboolib with Databricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am on the team at Databricks working on the bamboolib integration and I am excited that you want to take bamboolib for a spin.

Update: As of September 13 2022 bamboolib is in public preview within Databricks notebooks that use DBR 11 or higher (DBR 11.1 or higher on GCP).

[Link to the AWS docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/bamboolib.html)

Comment: Thanks Florian! It would be great having it available soon. I will appreciate if you can update this answer when having any updates :)

Comment: You're welcome and sure, I plan to update the answer. I want to let you know that customers who are enrolled in the private preview will get notified by the account team as well. This might be a better notification because this will ensure that the clusters that are available to you will be able to run bamboolib.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was solved after setting the Databricks Runtime to 11.0 version. Read more about the requirements of bamboolib on Databricks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/bamboolib#requirements (DBR 11.0 is the minimum requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You can install bamboolib library using below 2 approach.

1. `pip install bamboolib` - [link](https://pypi.org/project/bamboolib/)

[image]

2. Install library in databricks cluster.

[image]

You can refer this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bamboolib-learn-and-use-pandas-without-coding-23a7d3a94e1b) by Rahul Agarwal

Comment: Thanks but the issue is after the installation process when trying to use it with the GUI as explained by @fwetdb